# Apollo and React: refreshQueries not working in mutation fired from onClick()

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I'm building a simple shopping app. On load, we'll make a query to check whether a cart exists. For now, that query always returns `null` (I haven't implemented logic yet to check whether a user has a shopping cart already). Then, when a user clicks "create cart", we do a mutation to create it. Finally, we'll use `refreshQueries` after the mutation finishes to fetch the cart (and its products) by ID, which is returned from the mutation. We then render those products in a pure component.

The problem I'm encountering is that nothing re-renders after users click the button and `refreshQueries` happens. I know the query is being sent and returning a created cart with products by looking at my developer tools' network tab. It's just that Apollo doesn't seem to notice the change.

Mongo is my back-end.

Here's the relevant code:

```
// query
import { gql } from 'react-apollo';

export const cartQuery = gql`
  query CartQuery($cartId: ID) {
    cart(cartId: $cartId) {
      _id,
      products {
        _id,
        name
      }
    }
  }
`;

// mutation
import { gql } from 'react-apollo';

export const createCartMutation = gql`
  mutation CreateCartMutation {
    createCart {
      _id
    }
  }
`;

// Apollo + React stuff
import React from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';

import { createCartMutation } from '../../mutations';
import { cartQuery } from '../../queries';

const BuildCart = ({ mutate }) => (
  <button
    onClick={() => {
      // even when I hardcode the ID of a cart that exists and contains products, it doesn't matter
      mutate({
        refetchQueries: [{ query: cartQuery, variables: { cartId: '12345abcd' } }],
      });
    }}
  >
    Click
  </button>
);

const BuildCartConnected = graphql(createCartMutation)(BuildCart);

const Cart = ({ data, data: { cart, loading } }) => {
  console.log(cart); // always null, even after clicking button
  return (
    <div>
      <BuildCartConnected />
      {loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
      // never gets to this step, even though the response is a properly formed cart with an array of products
      {cart && cart.products.map(product => (
        <p key={Math.random()}>{product.name}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const CartConnected = graphql(cartQuery)(Cart);

export default CartConnected;
```

If it's helpful, here's what the response from `refetchQueries` looks like in the network tab:
`{"data":{"cart":{"_id":"12345abcd","products":[{"_id":"abcdef12345","name":"Product A","__typename":"Product"}],"__typename":"Cart"}}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `cart` query takes a `cartId` variable. In the code above, you're not providing that variable, so its value is undefined. Apollo associates that combination of query plus variable(s) with your `Cart` component.

When you call refetch queries with a *different* variable than what is provided to the HOC, the results of that new query are fetched and persisted in the store. However, as far as Apollo knows, you still want the results of a query with undefined as the variable value for that component, not this new result you had it fetch.

`refetchQueries` shouldn't be utilized for what you're trying to do. Instead, the variable for the `cart` query should be derived from props:

```
const options = ({cartId}) => ({variables: {cartId}})
const CartConnected = graphql(cartQuery, {options})(Cart)
```

Then, when you call `mutate`, it returns a Promise that will resolve to the data returned by the mutation. We can grab the cartId from the response and store it within application state (by calling `setState`, firing off a Redux action, etc.). You can then pass that state down to your `Cart` component as a prop. When the state is updated, the prop changes and the query with the newly provided variable is fetched.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's getting me on the right track. However, even when I do call my `Cart` query with the `cartId` variable initially, clicking the button still does nothing.

Comment: Hard to know exactly what's wrong without looking at all the code. You could put up a gist or a repo link and I could take a look.

Comment: refetchQueries literally NEVER works. It's so frustrating how under documented this is.